# WAMP running two Websites with two Static IP's

Tags: wamp

I have a windows server 2016 with two static IP addresses

IP - 1 is linked to a site in c:\wamp\www
IP - 2 I want to link to a site in c:\wamp\www\site1

Currently I have used https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/creating-multiple-virtual-websites-in-wampserver/ this to create two sites but the problem I have it is all on one IP range

I need for site A to use either localhost or a static IP and site B to use it's own IP so I can direct the domain to that IP ranges

In short

www.siteA.com - 100.0.0.1 ~
www.siteB.com - 100.0.0.2

How can I achieve this as currently I have to user 100.0.0.1/site1 to obtain site B and 100.0.0.1 to get Site A

Comment: Do you have a DNS Server on your Windows Server?

Comment: I have not installed it but have access to it to install yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution to running two websites on WAMP server pointing to two different IP addresses

I have changed the http-vhost file as follow

```
<VirtualHost *:80> //This I left as * as this was already running on 127.0.0.1 local host, it can be changed to your static IP Address as required
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 154.*.166.*:80> //this can be your second IP address you directing to
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/etrack"
    ServerName etrack
    ServerAlias **
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also made changes in the host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost   #eTrack GPS Tracking Software //pointing my first site to local host again
154.*.166.*       etrack        #eTrack Platform Software //pointing my second site to static IP
```

The files can be found in the following directory.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc host

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra